# Togglz Feature Switch - How to implement ActivationStategy for multiple Id's/parms that have same logic(same logic in strategy for combinations)

Tags: java, togglz

Here is my quesion,

I have a feature switch with a custom strategy named "**UserActivationStrategy**".
All it does is, it has a hard coded value as '**user**' in **Id** field and a '**IpAddress**' as **param** and some logic to return true/false in **isActive(state,user)**.

So **strategy** to be invoked is determined based on hard coded **Id**. Here is my application.properties with those defined

```
CustomFeature = true
CustomFeature.strategy= user
CustomFeature.param.IpAddress= xx.xx.xxx
```

The above tells that ....UserActivationStrategy is invoked based on Id('user') which is hard coded in strategy. In UserActivationStrategy  I am verfying the Ipaddress and returning true/false.

**So what if I need to perform same logic on different users with different IpAddress. Its like combinations. Certain user's have access to certain IpAddress.**

I cannot create feature switch for each user or for each IPAddress. It would creates many feature switches.

If I add  users and IPAddress as params in a strategy. I end up creating many params in single strategy which is not good.

Any solution to this is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: @chkal could you help me with this

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I fully understand what you are trying to achieve. So you have a single feature flag and if activated, it should evaluate to `true` if and only if a certain combination of user and IP address are present?

If so, you should perhaps create a single strategy which can be configured using a string which encodes all allowed combinations. Something like:

```
user1=127.0.0.1, user2=127.0.0.2, user3=127.0.0.3
```

You can then configure this configuration string in the admin console. Or directly add it to the configuration file:

```
CustomFeature = true
CustomFeature.strategy= user
CustomFeature.param.combintations=user1=127.0.0.1, user2=127.0.0.2
```

The strategy would have to parse this representation and check for one of the allowed combinations.

Comment: Thanks @chkal for looking into this. It seems you got what I am trying to say. But slight change its many to many mappings which I need to define. So user1=127.0.0.1,127.0.0.2,127.0.0.3,127.0.0.4...so on and user2 = 127.0.0.1,127.0.0.2 and user3 = 127.0.0.1,127.0.0.2,127.0.0.3 ...in this way i have many to many combinations that i need to define for feature switch. so how should i define configuration and strategy for this scenario's

Comment: You could also encode the many to many relationship in a strategy parameter. Something like: user1=127.0.0.1,127.0.0.2;user2=127.0.0.1...

Comment: However, please note that I'm not completely sure whether or not this is really a use case for Togglz. This sound a bit more like a permission requirement.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out the solution for this. In my features.properties I have list of users as param.

Example:

```
CustomFeature.param.user1=127.0.0.1,127.0.0.2
CustomFeature.param.user2=127.0.0.1,127.0.0.3
```

So I am  getting the featurestate.getparameter(user1) in my activation strategy that returns all the IPAddress. So based on that IPaddress iam enabling/disabling the feature switch.

So this startegy avoid me from creating many params/feature swtiches.